# Use a cell reference for the connection in GetWebTable

Tags: excel, web-scraping, reference, web, vba

I'm trying to pull the tables from WSJ Futures but I want to be able to change the date in the web address. My hope is to use the code below but make the website a cell reference. Any ideas on how to make this work or a different code that would get me the same result with a cell reference for the website?

```
Sub GetWebTable()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3023-fut_metal-futures-20170901.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar", Destination:=Range("a1"))
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will fetch you the table. Take a closer look at this `Connection:="URL;" & URL,` portion in the script. You messed up there.

```
Sub GetWebTable()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3023-fut_metal-futures-20170901.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT:

If you like to parse any specific table other than all, you just need to find it's index number just as i did below:

```
Sub GetWebTable()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3023-fut_metal-futures-20170901.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .WebTables = "3" 'You can parse any specific table as well. For more than one table change the parameter "2,3" like this
        .Refresh
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This pulls the table but because it also has the web address coded it pulls today's data every time and doesn't follow the A1 address with a changing date. (the date is the 20170901 portion of the code) Any other ideas on how to get around the calendar function?